# How do I get my code to show the key in the console?

Tags: javascript, html

```
let formDataContainer = new Array();

function appendFormData(firstNamePar, lastNamePar, messagePar) {

    function Person(firstNamePar, lastNamePar, messagePar){
        this.first_Name = firstNamePar;
        this.last_Name = lastNamePar;
        this.my_Message = messagePar;
    }

    let person1 = new Person(firstNamePar, lastNamePar, messagePar);
    formDataContainer.push(person1);
};

submitButton.addEventListener('click', appendFormData(firstName.value, lastName.value, message.value));
console.log(formDataContainer[0]);
```

BUT MY OUTPUT IS:

> Person {first_Name: '', last_Name: '', my_Message: ''}

AND NOT:

> Person {first_Name: 'Raven', last_Name: 'Volt', my_Message: 'Hello world'}

Comment: Please have a look at the tools available in the post editor and use them to properly format your code and messages. Also, your question needs more explanation. See [ask].

Comment: you are calling console.log when the formDataContainer is still an empty array. The event listener appending data to the array is going to be executed only once the click event will be triggered.. but the console.log was executed as soon as the page was loaded. You should put that console.log inside the event handler function. Plus the way you are adding the listener is weird. You have to pass a function there.. not an invocation like that. Otherwise it will just add an undefined to the click event of that button written like you did.

Comment: You are calling `appendFormData` and assigning what it returns to the click handler. You are not calling `appendFormData` on click.

Answer (score 0):

change the code to this

```
let formDataContainer = new Array();

function appendFormData(firstNamePar, lastNamePar, messagePar) {

    function Person(firstNamePar, lastNamePar, messagePar){
        this.first_Name = firstNamePar;
        this.last_Name = lastNamePar;
        this.my_Message = messagePar;
    }

    let person1 = new Person(firstNamePar, lastNamePar, messagePar);
    formDataContainer.push(person1);
};

submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => appendFormData(firstName.value, lastName.value, message.value));
console.log(formDataContainer[0]);
```

you are calling `appendFormData`  when you were declaring the event listener

Comment: Thanks guys it works now, Special thanks to you @Diego De Vita.